# Objc iOS7 navigationBar after pressed home button, return the apps navigationBar appeared

Tags: iphone, ios

iOS 6 doesn't have this problem,
But in iOS 7. after pressed the home button and return to apps
The navigationBar appears

Image 1:(Before)
[image]

Image 2:(After click Home Btn)

[image]

Code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0f;
```

And I've tried using

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Thanks.

Comment: iOS7 is still under NDA, this could mean that no one will answer your question.

Comment: you could use `[self.navigatoinController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` instead of setting alpha and translucent.

Comment: iOS 7 is Under NDA so don't ask related to iOS 7 question :)

Comment: Thanks, all.
I had tried to set 
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES], 
and keep trying.